# Masked Textbox Format in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm doing a Textbox masking for WPF. I get an error when I delete the character lines in the Textbox Text.

**What I want to do is**

I have a masking format like **XXXX / XXXX / XXXX / XXXX**

I want the **XXXX / XXXX / XXXX / XXXX** characters back to the Textbox box automatically if the user deletes the Textbox content when they make an incorrect entry.

Can I group user deletions?

For example, format XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-TTTT. Can I delete group by X, Y, Y, T values?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="280">
    <local:MyMaskedTextBox x:Name="MaskedDemo" Mask="0000/0000/0000/0000" StayInFocusUntilValid="True" IgnoreSpace="True" Width="180" Height="26" Margin="20"/>
    <Button Content="OK" Height="24" Width="50"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**MyMaskedTextBox.cs**

```
{
class MyMaskedTextBox : TextBox
{
    private System.ComponentModel.MaskedTextProvider _mprovider = null;
    public string Mask
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mprovider != null) return _mprovider.Mask;
            else return "";
        }
        set
        {
            _mprovider = new System.ComponentModel.MaskedTextProvider(value);
            this.Text = _mprovider.ToDisplayString();
        }
    }

    private bool PreviousInsertState = false;

    private bool _InsertIsON = false;
    private bool _stayInFocusUntilValid = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets whether the focus should stay on the control until the contents are valid
    /// </summary>
    public bool StayInFocusUntilValid
    {
        get { return _stayInFocusUntilValid; }
        set { _stayInFocusUntilValid = value; }
    }

    private bool _NewTextIsOk = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines whether the next entered input text is ok according to the mask
    /// </summary>
    public bool NewTextIsOk
    {
        get { return _NewTextIsOk; }
        set { _NewTextIsOk = value; }
    }

    private bool _ignoreSpace = true;
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets whether space should be ignored
    /// </summary>
    public bool IgnoreSpace
    {
        get { return _ignoreSpace; }
        set { _ignoreSpace = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the effect of some common keys
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.SelectionLength > 1)
        {
            this.SelectionLength = 0;
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Insert || e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Back || (e.Key == Key.Space && _ignoreSpace))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// We check whether we are ok
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.MaskedTextResultHint hint;
        int TestPosition;

        if (e.Text.Length == 1)
            this._NewTextIsOk = _mprovider.VerifyChar(e.Text[0], this.CaretIndex, out hint);
        else
            this._NewTextIsOk = _mprovider.VerifyString(e.Text, out TestPosition, out hint);

        base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When text is received by the TextBox we check whether to accept it or not
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnTextInput(System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        string PreviousText = this.Text;
        if (NewTextIsOk)
        {
            base.OnTextInput(e);
            if (_mprovider.VerifyString(this.Text) == false) this.Text = PreviousText;
            while (!_mprovider.IsEditPosition(this.CaretIndex) && _mprovider.Length > this.CaretIndex) this.CaretIndex++;

        }
        else
            e.Handled = false; //true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the TextBox takes the focus we make sure that the Insert is set to Replace
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        if (!_InsertIsON)
        {
            PressKey(Key.Insert);
            _InsertIsON = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the textbox looses the keyboard focus we may want to verify (based on the StayInFocusUntilValid) whether
    /// the control has a valid value (fully complete)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (StayInFocusUntilValid)
        {
            _mprovider.Clear();
            _mprovider.Add(this.Text);
            if (!_mprovider.MaskFull) e.Handled = true;
        }

        base.OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simulates pressing a key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key to be pressed</param>
    private void PressKey(Key key)
    {
        KeyEventArgs eInsertBack = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
                                                    Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
                                                    0, key);
        eInsertBack.RoutedEvent = KeyDownEvent;
        InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(eInsertBack);
    }
}
```

}

I'm making a mistake somewhere. where is the error?

Comment: What Error you get?

Comment: I can not enter a value into the TextBox again because the mask object (XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX) is deleted when I enter an incorrect value in the Textbox and delete it

Comment: But you want that user can delete the other numbers right? only not allow to delete the "/" mark ?

Comment: No brackets are automatically loaded from the masking process. If the user erases the separator between the quartet groups, such as / or -, the masking operation is erroneous and the data input operation can not be performed again 
 @Kaspar

Comment: Yes, but it is often that the delete operation is not allowed in the masked, and I wonder if that could be a solution for you. So user can not delete anything only replace?

Comment: Actually when the user enters an incorrect value, I delete the value in the Textbox, but I want to reload the mask delimiters. Because if the mask is not reloaded into the Textbox, the program error. Mask value should not be null. @Kaspar

Comment: I will just set e.Handled to true when Key.Delete. it is much safer. If you would like that user can delete you need to just replace the delete char with the "_" char once again, if the deleter char is "-" just replace it with "-", please let me know if you know how to these? If no I will write a solution but later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution, it will not allow to delete the seperation mark, and also when you delete some number it will replace it by "_". Change the one method. 
Also inside the  if for delete key I e.Handled is set to true, that no deletion is performed, only logic implemented inside the if statement.

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.SelectionLength > 1)
    {
        this.SelectionLength = 0;
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    if (e.Key == Key.Insert || e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Back || (e.Key == Key.Space && _ignoreSpace))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.Text);
        if (sb[CaretIndex - 1] != '-')
        {
            sb[CaretIndex - 1] = '_';
        }
        this.Text = sb.ToString();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

Please let me know if solution works!. It works for me.

Comment: This method works. The lines are rewritten silently. But it does not work properly. Every time the cursor is clicked, the cursor is at index 0 of the TextBox, so it does not work exactly. How do we fix this? @Kaspar

Comment: The problem was solved with a few regulations. Thanks @Kaspar